# Join on multiple fields

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying todo a join with LINQ on multiple fields but I keep getting following error:

**Error:**

*The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.*

**LINQ query:**

```
var query =  from s in _dbContext.Samples
                 join sp in _dbContext.UserSampleTypePurposes on new {SampleTypeId = s.SampleTypeID, PurposeId = s.PurposeID} equals new { SampleTypeId = sp.SampleTypeId, PurposeId = sp.PurposeId}
             select s;
```

SamplteTypeId and and purposeId are foreign keys to the respective tables.

**system:**

dotnet core 2.2.102

Someone an idea how to fix this? or do it differently?

Comment: Is the type of columns `SampleTypeID` and `PurposeID` the same for both tables? That is, `int` I suppose.

Comment: Yes both of type int

Comment: Ow wait I found the problem: one was of type int? and other of type int 
Thxs for the help! Totally missed that.